# Fetch records from Sqlite based on WHERE condition

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to sqlite and android development.

Below is my query to fetch records based on a WHERE condition

```
 Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT  * "
                    + " FROM  " +  ExpenditureDbSchema.ExpenditureTable.NAME
                    + " WHERE  " + "   strftime('%mm'," + ExpenditureDbSchema.ExpenditureTable.Cols.PURCHASE_DATE + "/1000" + " ,'unixepoch') = 6"                 
            , null);
```

I have written above raw query to fetch records which were purchased in the month of June.
My table has few records for which month of purchase date is June , but still the above query does not return any records.

Please let me know what is the mistake or issue in above query , also let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: If your months in table are numbers, purchase_date = 6 should solve it.  Why do you use strftime('%mm'," + ExpenditureDbSchema.ExpenditureTable.Cols.PURCHASE_DATE + "/1000" + " ,'unixepoch')?

Comment: Also if you are just beginning to learn SQLite skip it, and learn Room.